# Manejo de un elemento de una lista en python

Tags: python

Nesecito manipular un elemento entero de una lista, supongamos que en dicha lista esta asi:

Lista = [123432, 2345321, 234554]

Quiero obtener un nuevo numero de los centros de cada elmento de la lista
Me refiero a que si el numero tiene 5 digitos, tomar los digitos del 2 al 4, en caso de ser 7 , tomar los digitos del 3 al 5

nuevaLista = [234, 453, 345] -- el numero de digitos a tomar depende de una valiable "k" ingresada por el usuario

Mi unica duda es como puedo acceder a la mitad de los enteros de la lista, solo se me ocurre hace una nueva lista para cada elemento , hacer split y manipular los digitos como elementos de una litsa, pero aun me queda la duda de si es una forma correcta de hacerlo y sobre todo sigo teniendo la duda de como obtener esos elementos de en medio.

Comment: Disculpa, pero en el caso de `123432` que son 6 dígitos no tendría que imprimir 343 siendo k = 3?

Comment: Bueno, en realidad no importa, el caso que estoy estudiando anexa un cero a la izquierda para hacer que el numero tenga punto medio, por eso en numeros con digitos pares el centro se ve recorrido a la izquierda, pero al fin y al cabo lo que intento obtener es un numero aleatorio por lo que no es importante si el centro esta recorrido a la derecha o a la izquierda

Comment: Ahí agregué una respuesta, fijate si te sirve y cualquier cosa nos avisas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El concepto de este código es ir quitando el ultimo y el primer elemento del número, hasta que nos quedemos la cantidad "k" de números.

```
lista = [12345, 123456, 1234567]

def central_number(number):
    str_number = str(number)
    sobrantes = len(str_number) - k

    if sobrantes >= 0:
        separate_last_element = True
        for sobrante in range( 0, sobrantes ):
            if separate_last_element:
                str_number = str_number[0:-1]
            else: # Separate the first element
                str_number = str_number[1: ]

            separate_last_element = not separate_last_element

        return int( str_number )

k = 3
print map( central_number, lista  )
k = 4
print map( central_number, lista  )
k = 5
print map( central_number, lista  )
```

Comment: me parece que la eficasia se paga con mas lineas de codigo jajaja, en efecto me has ayudado, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar esto (Python 2.7):

```
lista = [123432, 2345321, 234554]
nueva_lista = []
k = 3
for num in lista:
    num = str(num) # Lo hago string para poder saber la longitud
    mitad = len(num)/2 - 1 # Saco la mitad
    nueva_lista.append(int(num[mitad : mitad + k])) # Lo agrego a la nueva lista convertido en int

print(nueva_lista)
```

Output:

```
[343, 453, 455]
```

**Nota:** para Python 3.5 deberías modificar la siguiente línea:

```
mitad = len(num)//2 - 1 # Saco la mitad
```

Ya que en Python 3.5 todas las divisiones retornan un flotante

Espero que te haya servido! Saludos

Comment: Tu codigo funciona bien, pero cuando cambio la variable k por un numero mayor a tres, el centro se desplaza a la derecha, por ejemplo si k = 4 , y tengo un entero de 20214016 , el output sería 1401.

Comment: sería cuestion de modificar la linea donde calculas la mitad , cuando le restas las posiciones le pones -1, como puedo saber cuanto restarle dependiendo del valor de k?

Comment: ok, deacuerdo, te agradesco la ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Perdón! Creí que eras otro usuario ajeno a la pregunta! Considerando que necesitas de esa manera que decís ahí edito la respuesta. Nuevamente disculpas

Comment: El tema es así, cuando pongo se hace la división el numero se redonde para abajo (se descartan los decimales), entonces con k = 5 la division quedaría 2, y le puse el -1 para que corresponda al index de la lista que empieza en 0. Espero que puedas ajustar el código a tu medida, así no te genero mas confusión. Saludos!

Comment: Si, ya lo entendí, me funciona perfecto, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que sabes cómo extraer la mitad, el resto no tiene mayor problema:

```
def mitad(s,k):
    m = max((len(s)-k)//2, 0)
    return s[m:m+k]

lista = [123432, 2345321, 234554]
k = 3

nueva_lista = [int(mitad(str(i),k)) for i in lista]
```

Comment: Orale, me gusta mas tu metodo, pero creo que sería injusto quitarle los puntos a quien me resolvio la duda antes, pero definitivamente esto era lo que buscaba, algo sencillo, veo que me estaba complicando mas de lo que perece, garcias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Eres libre de aplicar tu criterio. Me conformo de sobras con que sirva a quien busque esta pregunta. Lo extraño es que sólo haya un voto, y que ni la respuesta aceptada ni la mía tenga ningú voto. Más importante que la elección de la mejor respuesta, es que los lectores voten las respuestas que creean interesantes.

Comment: Es verdad, para eso esta la comunidad, espero aportar lo mio tambien